# Why do Pelicans seem to disappear when circling high in the sky on a sunny day

Tags: zoology

When I watch Pelicans circling high in the sky on a sunny day, at a certain point in that circle, they disappear from view, then reappear again further along in that circle.
Is it something to do with the angle of the sun reflecting off the feathers?